# State/Province dropdown is empty since update to 4.6.10

Tags: 4.6.10

I just discovered that the State/Province dropdown in Address section of create New Individual form is missing the state data. When I click on the dropdown it displays "N/A" and below it "None found.". This seems to be a universal problem in my civicrm instance too - e.g when i go to to manage an Event the dropdown behaves the same.

I have never noticed this problem before in 5+ years of running civicrm. I recently upgraded to 4.6.10 from 4.6.3 - perhaps its related. This is a WordPress 4.3.1 install.

I checked the 'civicrm_state_province' table in the db and the data is there, so i'm not sure why it's not getting loaded in the dropdown.

any ideas?

screenshot of broken dropdown: [http://imgur.com/3w3G8On](https://imgur.com/3w3G8On)

Comment: do you have any error displayed on console ? If yes, can you please paste them here ?

Comment: I turned on the Inspector in mozilla and I don't see any relevant errors.  Here is screenshot for source for that dropdown.. http://imgur.com/naB9o1j    Does the 'href="javascript:void(0)' indicate a problem?

Comment: I tried also to play with settings in Administrater -> Localization and the States data does not load there either http://imgur.com/zK8ZpzQ

Comment: The state/province is based upon the country.  I assume you probably don't have the field for country shown.  You might add it temporarily to see if it's populated.  You might also check to see if the default is still set in Admin=>Localizations=>Languages, Currencies, Locations

Comment: Thanks Paul, but the problem is expressing itself even in the Localization area.. screen shot: http://imgur.com/zK8ZpzQ

Comment: Could the problem have to do this jqState script? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14631

Comment: On closer examination with Firebug i'm seeing that civicrm/ajax/jqState is not returning data.. the JSON object is empty, but I don't see any errors thrown in the Console

Comment: This problem has been resolved.. The civicrm_state_province table was empty. dumb of me not to check this, How it got empty is a mystery tho...

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been resolved.. The civicrm_state_province table was empty. dumb of me not to check this, How it got empty is a mystery tho...

Answer (score 0):

If your upgrade failed at some point and you had to restore from backup, then your system might have enough data to make it seem like you restored successfully, but it might be missing the last several tables of CiviCRM.